# Функция принимает массив, количество элементов, а возвращает указатель на элемент

Tags: c++

В задаче есть класс и функция, не принадлежащая классу.
Не могу понять, как функция может возвращать указатель на элемент массива.
Дайте кто-нибудь пример такой функции, а то не могу додуматься.

Comment: Где этот массив хранится, в глобальной переменной или как поле класса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оператор + для массива возвращает указатель. Пример:

```
int foo[] = {0, 5, 10, 15};
int *bar = foo + 2;
```

В этом случае указатель bar будет указывать на третий элемент массива (значение 10). Вот пример функций возвращающих указатель на начало и конец массива:

```
int* array_begin(int arr[]) {
    return arr;
}

int* array_end(int *arr, size_t arr_size) {
    return arr + (arr_size - 1);
}
```

Использование функций:

```
int foo[] = {0, 5, 10, 15};
int *foo_begin = array_begin(foo);
int *foo_end = array_end(foo, sizeof(foo) / sizeof(int));
```

Существует более универсальный способ определить размер массива, а соответственно и смещение:

```
template <std::size_t N> int* array_end(int (&arr)[N]) {
    return arr + (N - 1);
}
```

Но это будет когда разберетесь с шаблонами...

Answer (score 1):

Например:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
const T* find(const T* arr, size_t size, const T& value)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        if (arr[i] == value)
            return &arr[i]; // собственно, именно здесь мы возвращаем указатель на элемент массива.
    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    const int* p = find(arr, 4, 3);
    cout << p << endl;
    p = find(arr, 4, 42);
    cout << p << endl;
    return 0;
}
```